# Data not passing correctly with wp_localize_script

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm trying to pass PHP data to a JS script.
I'm using the wp_localize_script function.

```
wp_register_script('googlechart', 'https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js');
wp_register_script('mygaloochart_script', plugins_url('chart.js', __FILE__), array('googlechart'));

//I'm not using $atts directly for reasons
$dataToBePassed = array (
        'chart' => $atts['chart'],
        'element' => $atts['element'],
        'elementtype' => $atts['elementtype'],
        'title' => $atts['title']
);

wp_localize_script('mygaloochart_script', 'php_vars', $datatoBePassed);

wp_enqueue_script('googlechart');
wp_enqueue_script('mygaloochart_script');
```

This is the first line of the JS script `mygaloochart_script`:

```
console.log(php_vars.chart);
```

However, I get the following error in the console:

```
TypeError: php_vars is null
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The name of your array is `$dataToBePassed`. However you are passing `$datatoBePassed` in your `wp_localize_script` function. Big T, small t. **PHP** variable names are **case sensitive**.

Comment: To the people coming to this from tutsplus here is where the mistake began: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-pass-php-data-and-strings-to-javascript-in-wordpress--wp-34699

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to comment due to my reputation. Just curious to ask, did you hook the function something like the below?

**Update**

```
function add_vars_to_js(){

wp_register_script('googlechart', 'https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js');
wp_register_script('mygaloochart_script', plugins_url('chart.js', __FILE__), array('googlechart'));

//I'm not using $atts directly for reasons
$dataToBePassed = array (
        'chart' => $atts['chart'],
        'element' => $atts['element'],
        'elementtype' => $atts['elementtype'],
        'title' => $atts['title']
);

wp_localize_script('mygaloochart_script', 'php_vars', $datatoBePassed);

wp_enqueue_script('googlechart');
wp_enqueue_script('mygaloochart_script');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_vars_to_js');
```

Comment: I didn't. Is this necessary? It's not mentionned in the `wp_localize_script` doc.

Comment: What should be the syntax? The function called in my script is called `drawChart()` (sorry, new to Wordpress!).

Comment: Updated the answer. If the js is for admin area, add the hook like this 

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'add_vars_to_js');

Comment: I'm getting `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare add_vars_to_js() (previously declared in C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\mygaloochart\chart.php:40) in C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\mygaloochart\chart.php on line 40`

Comment: This is an example of a function name. Try another name like olivier_function_js or whatever

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115081/discussion-between-olivier-grech-and-ayanize).

Comment: `$datatoBePassed` -> `$dataToBePassed`... It works now. Turns out the hook wasn't necessary.