# Wordpress execute javascript file only if user is not logged in

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, templates, include

I'm trying to execute a javascript file in wordpress only if the user is not logged in, but I can't see why it's not working. This is the code I'm using:

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
echo 'Ok!';
} else {
wp_enqueue_script(
'ads'
);
}
?>
```

And this is what I have in functions.php to register the file:

```
wp_register_script(
'ads',
get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/js/ads.js'
);
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you should use wp_localize_script 
 and read the object in your javascript. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37917798/data-not-passing-correctly-with-wp-localize-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) should be run on the [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) hook. This should also be encapsulated in a function, or at least a [closure/anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

> Side note, you'll want to start properly formatting/indenting code now - *future you* thanks you!

**A.** You're checking if a user "is" logged in. You can just make sure that [`is_user_logged_in()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/) is returning false with the use of the "Not" Logical Operator: `!`.

**B.** You don't need to register your script, as `wp_enqueue_script` will register it for you. You really only need to register scripts if you're getting more fancy like loading scripts only if a shortcode is active on a page.

**C.** Typically you'll want to prefix your script/style handles, since they [should be unique](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/#parameters), there can be conflicts otherwise.

**D.** Typically you'll want to use [`get_template_directory_uri()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/) or [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_directory_uri/) over `get_bloginfo()` since [`get_bloginfo( $directory_type )` is literally just a wrapper for those functions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72727/get-template-directory-vs-bloginfo-template-directory-vs-templatepath).

Something like this will get you started:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_ads_script' );
function load_ads_script(){
    if( !is_user_logged_in() ){
        // The "!" makes sure the user is _not_ logged in.
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jacob-k-ads', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/ads.js' );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't work at all. =/ The ad (popup) is not showing at all. This is the content of the js file: https://pastebin.com/raw/Zz9CbhJb

Comment: The function I gave you is correct, the contents of your JS file aren't correct, however. You can't actually have `<script>` tags in your `.js` files. You'll want to break up that script. Save your JS file with the code, starting at `K200` alll the way through and omit the last `</script>` tag. Inside your script though, is another remote script, which you'll have to load in. So once you update your JS file, enqueue the remote file _above_ your personal one: `wp_enqueue_script( 'clksite-adserve', '//p28173.clksite.com/adServe/banners?tid=28173_568703_0&tagid=2&hybridPop=true' );`